# referring objects and elements with each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery each code where i am trying to match the data set of the previous checkbox with current one, so if they do not match, just uncheck the checkbox, but seems i am missing something here

```
obj.each(function(i,e) {
  var refer = $(e); 
  if(e.checked && refer.prev(e.dataset.stid) != e.dataset.stid) {
    e.checked = false;
  } 
}
```

here i am not sure what is wrong, but it is not working, also i am trying to add a code that if there is no previous check, just exists from this block

Comment: Please share the HTML that goes along with this snippet. Regardless, I believe you're misusing/misunderstanding `.prev()`. `refer.prev(e.dataset.stid)` checks to see if the previous element satisfies the selector `e.dataset.stid`. If it does, it returns the element itself. If it doesn't, it returns `null`. If you want to get the `data-stid` attribute of the previous element, that'd be `refer.prev().data("stid")`.

Comment: `refer.prev(e.dataset.stid)` is a jQuery object and certainly won't equal anything else. Provide a *runnable* [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) is a jQuery method that can return one of two things: an element, or `null`.

Unless `e.dataset.stid` is `null` or `undefined`, the condition will always be satisfied, thus unchecking all your checkboxes.

To get the previous element's `data-stid` attribute, try comparing `refer.prev().data("stid")` instead.

```js
let obj = $("input[type=checkbox]");
obj.each(function(i,e) {
  if (i === 0) return;
  var refer = $(e);
  if(e.checked && refer.prev().data("stid") != e.dataset.stid) {
    e.checked = false;
  } 
});
```

```css
input:not(:nth-child(2)) { margin-left: 25px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-stid="1" checked> data-stid="1"
<input type="checkbox" data-stid="1" checked> data-stid="1"
<input type="checkbox" data-stid="0" checked> data-stid="0"
<input type="checkbox" data-stid="1" checked> data-stid="1"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not check if there is any prev object exists or not, or in other words, if this is the first item

Comment: You haven't described what should happen in that case,  shared your HTML, nor shared what `obj` refers to. Is "first" the first on the page? First in a container? What is the desired outcome?